# Why can't I plot chosen points?

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib, environment, ubuntu-13.10

In Matplotlib, Python, I want to click and mark points (actually, a point calculated from its position, eventually), but it doesn't seem to be possible. Even something simple like this doesn't work:

```
from pylab import *

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(np.random.rand(10))

def onclick(event):
    print 'button=%d, x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f'%(
        event.button, event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata)
    plt.plot(event.xdata,event.ydata,',')

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
show()
```

Comment: do you get an errors?

Comment: no, it just doesn't show

Answer (score 1):

`','` is the marker for a single pixel, try `'o'` or something larger instead.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(np.random.rand(10))

def onclick(event):
    print 'button=%d, x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f'%(
        event.button, event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata)
    ax.plot(event.xdata,event.ydata,'o')
    plt.draw_if_interactive()

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
show()
```

[image]

Comment: I used ',' as marker before. with o, no change, still doesn't work.

Comment: The code I posted works correctly on current master.  What version of mpl are you using?

Comment: @NoBugs Also, what backend?  Interactivity does not work in ipython notebooks

Comment: Version 1.2.1, using whatever Ubuntu default is.

Comment: @NoBugs Are you running this through an interactive shell or through a script?

Comment: I just saved the file and ran it. (Using Geany)

Comment: the interactive features do not always play nice with scripts, try the same code in an interactive session and I bet it will work.

Comment: Why would that be different? I need to copy paste to python terminal?

Comment: See the discussion here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2503  run your script with `python -i run.py`

Comment: Can you try running it in `ipython --pylab` (which makes sure all of the gui magic is started up properly) to verify that `matplotlib` is working correctly?

Comment: That works! It says "Welcome to pylab, a matplotlib-based Python environment [backend: TkAgg]." How do I set the backend from my python code though?

Comment: Why do you use draw_if_interactive() when draw() works perfectly, running the script as a file?

Comment: Because this is an interactive feature.